# Eclipse still runs project by old name

Tags: android, eclipse

I had a project named "xxx" which I renamed to "yyy". The project works fine on my phone. But Eclipse still says "Launching xxx" when I run the app. How do I remedy the situation? I've tried searching for "xxx" throughout my project, no luck.

Comment: Could the old name still be set in the Run or Debug Configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the launch configurations and have a look at the configuration that´s called `xxx`.
In the Name field you can edit the name of the launch configuration to whatever you want.

**EDIT:**
Maybe this documentation article makes it much more clearer:
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-editlaunchconfig.htm

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  The old name showing up was driving me nuts!

Comment: I'm having the same problem but this didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem on my Android project. Now I found the solution:

1. Click the **down arrow** next to the run button.
2. Select the **Run Configurations** item in the popup menu.
3. Expand **Android Application** and select the item with old project name.
4. Set the **Name:** field at right to the new project name.
5. Click **Apply**

Hope this can fix your problem.

Comment: this was the problem for me. THanks m8